# Rails get url_for working inside model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, url

Title says it all. It's pretty easy from controllers - just using "view_context". But it doesn't work with models.

E.g `ApplicationController.new.view_context.url_for` yields in: "undefined method 'host' for nil:NilClass"

`ActionView::Base.new(Rails.configuration.paths["app/views"].first).url_for` doesn't work as well.

Can this be done without so much pain ?

P.S I need it for my Prawn gem! I wanted to generate the PDF from the model. And apart from generating the links inside of it - it is very successful!

Hope for your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713571/view-helper-link-to-in-model-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might depend on Rails version, but generally this method is now defined in `Rails.application.routes`. It expects you to provide hash with url_options, with `:host` key among others.

Comment: Thank you! But can I somehow skip the :host part ? It should be determined automatically, right ?

Comment: @samuli, please take a look ;)

Comment: I'd really like to help, but I don't know the answer :) I was struggling with similar problem, not so long ago, but without success.

Answer (score 4):

Rails 5

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

url_for(myModelObject)
```