# user_path in User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, link-to

Is it possible to get the user_path in the User model? 
I'm trying to implement the following method:

```
def link_path
   link_to self.name, user_path(self.id_
end
```

But i'm getting that user_path is undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes this is correct, should have seen this. My apologies.

Comment: Don't apologize, elaborate. *Why* do you think, you need the URL helper in your model?

Comment: @user1596679 While there may be duplicates of your question, don't accept the answer in that thread without first considering using helpers. A lot of people are ignoring "the rails way" here...

Answer (score 1):

How about ...

```
def link_path
  Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.user_path(self)
end
```

I've done this sort of thing in APIs - where I want the url to the site to be in the json of the API response.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of method usually sits in a helper:

```
UsersHelper.rb

def user_link_path(user)
  link_to user.name, user_path(user)
end
```

View:

```
<%= user_link_path(user) %>
```

You [can use url helpers in your models](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8916129/385532) if you really want to, but I don't see any reason to for what you're doing, so may as well do it the rails way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341143/can-rails-routing-helpers-i-e-mymodel-pathmodel-be-used-in-models